# How to Run a Conditional Statement in TradingView Pine-Script?

Tags: python, switch-statement, conditional-statements, pine-script

After looking through the Pine-Script documentation I could not figure out there "Switch" style conditional statement.

I'm trying to subtract the opening and the closing from only the green candles.

**This is my current code:**

```
//@version=3 study(title="High Minus Low", shorttitle="HM0", overlay=true)

openall  = high[0]+high[1]+high[2]
closeall = open[0]+open[1]+open[2] total = openall + closeall

plot(total)
```

I only want to grab the latest 3 green candle bars using a conditional statement.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you use nested if's?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "switch" statement in PineScript. However you may use 'if' statements for your task. For example

```
green_delta = 0.0
if close > open
    green_delta := open - close 
plot(green_delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pinescript v5 supports `switch` statements: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_switch